# Who is in the post-credits scene of the Avengers movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, character-identification, the-avengers-2012

In the post-credits scene of the Avengers movie, we are shown a face who is presumably recognizable.  Who's is it?  All answers in spoiler tags please, for those who have not seen the movie.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two of my friends (who are much more up with Marvel than I) said:

> It was Thanos ( http://marvel.com/universe/Thanos ). Which makes sense as he's had a few fights against the Avengers according to the wiki.

Comment: The scene was [leaked online](http://www.worstpreviews.com/headline.php?id=24627&count=0). After watching it, I agree with your friends' conclusion. The key line "... to court Death" confirmed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about post credits but the mid credits scene, He is revealed to be the one who provided Loki with the Chitauri army. When told by his accomplice (known simply as "The Other") that battling The Avengers would be to court Death,

> Thanos flashes an evil grin.

Answer (score 3):

It's

> Thanos.

It ain't a Skrull, it ain't Darkseid, it ain't the Easter Bunny. It's

> Thanos.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Marvel super villain called

> Thanos,

just google him and you'll see how he's connected. Joss Whedon has used a story arc called

> "The First Thanos War" in which he invades earth in search of the Cosmic Cube.

Comment: No need for repetition. This has already been covered by 3 other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly

> Thanos. I have the Marvel figurine which looks exactly like this! Also, the "courting death" reference is definitely a Thanos storyline.

BTW the film was awesome.

Comment: I'll reiterate... this answer has already been given (multiple times). There's no need to post a duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

I think it's pretty much

> a skrull.

They're one of the baddest villains in the Marvel galaxy, i.e. Secret Invasion, etc. It was said that there was a possibility of them being the main villains in the Avengers film but it was denied by the people in Avengers.  It was a great easter egg — I screamed when I saw it in the cinema.

Comment: Um...no.  It isn't a Skrull.  Also, the Chitauri (aka: Loki's Army) are based on the Ultimates enemy of the same name...who, in turn, were based on the Skrulls.  We don't see them shapeshift in the movie, true, but they are the Skrulls.  Either the film Skrulls can't shapeshift, or they didn't think they needed to what with the whole 'direct, obvious invasion' thing.